# Question about asymptotic stability in ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying for a exam in ordinary differential equations and got stuck on this question:

> Show that if the origin is asymptotically stable for one of the following systems of ode's then the same holds for the other one
>
> 1) $x'=f(x)$
>
> 2) $x'=f(x)h(x)$
>
> $f$ is $C^1(R^n,R^n),f(0) = 0$ and $h$ is $C^1(R^n,R)$ , $h(0)>0$.

I have no idea where to start on this one. I'm also confused about the "$h(0) = 0$ and $h$ is $C^1(R^n,R)$ , $h(0)>0$." part. Can't make sense of it.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Per

Comment: <s>Probably the original problem says $f(0)=0$?</s> Ok found your question in http://www.math.chalmers.se/Math/Grundutb/GU/MMA421/S13/Doku/mma421_120605.pdf

Comment: OK, I too checked out the original problem and it says $f(x) \in C^1(R^n, R^n)$, $h(0) = 0$; then a few words later says $h(0) > 0$.  I think the statement $h(0) = 0$ is a misprint and it is supposed to read $f(0)= 0$; *that* reading makes sense and doesn't contradict itself.

Comment: Also olease note the cited exam says $f \in C^1(R^n, R^n)$, *not* $f \in C^1(R^n, R^m)$.  This too makes more sense since we are (apparently) dealing with an ODE on $R^n$!

Comment: peterwhy yeah that is the original exam.

@RobertLewis Sorry, that was a typo from my part. To summarize, its f(0) = 0 and h(0) > 0 ?

Comment: @Per:  that's my take on it.  Also, $f \in C^1(R^n, R^n)$ is an important observation.

Comment: @RobertLewis Hmmm.. Could you give me one more hint?

Comment: @Per:  my comments weren't really meant to be "hints", rather guesses as to what the correct formulation of the problem should be; but if they helped, I'm gratified.  Question:  what is your definition of asymptotic stability?  If the answer is too long for a comment, perhaps you could edit the question.  As for further hints, I'm thinking about and I'll let you know when I've got something.  Good question, though, +1!

Comment: @RobertLewis Haha, I thought the part about f∈C1(Rn,Rn) was a hint on how to approach the problem!

I define asymptotic stability: lim n --> inf |Phi(t,x) - x_0| = 0. Where Phi is the flow and x_0 the fixed point.

Comment: @Per:  you mean $\lim_{t \to \infty} \vert \phi(t, x) - x_0 \vert = 0$, right?  Not $\lim_{n \to \infty} etc.$.

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes. Sorry for all of the typos and confusion, been at this too long.

Answer (score 1):

Since $h$ is continuously differentiable and $h(0)>0$, $h$ does not vanish in a neighborhood of the origin. It follows that the vector fields $f$ and $h\cdot f$ points in the same direction (in a neighborhood of the origin). Hence they produce the same trajectories but with possibly different velocities (i.e. different parametrization for the same geometric curve). Therefore asymptotic stability of one vector field is equivalent to the asymptotic stability of the other.

Another way to see this, is by mean of converse Lyapunov theorem.